# Best SQL table design

Tags: sql

Which design is better for a table of products with probably more than one name per product?

Using one table or two tables:

```
One Table: 

id       |   Price|EN name| CH name|  JP name|.... 
---------------------------------------------------
1        |     100|    ABC|   中文一|     null|...
2        |     200|    CDE|    null|     null|...
.....    |     ...|    ...|     ...|      ...|...




Two Tables:
id       |   Price|EN name|  
---------------------------
1        |     100|    ABC|
2        |     200|    CDE|    
.....    |     ...|    ...|     


id       |   language|   name| 
-------------------------------
1        |         CH|  中文一|    
3        |         JP|    東京|     
.....    |       ... |    ...|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, two tables is considered "better", because it makes it easier to add new languages.  I will say that this might apply more to languages that share a common character set.

In many databases, expanding the width of a row (by adding more languages) has an effect on performance as well.  Wider rows are more expensive.  And adding columns to table with many rows is expensive.

One advantage of a single table is that you can define the character set for each column appropriate to that column, instead of having one generic column for all character sets.

In other words, there is not necessarily a simple answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The second way allows you to add extra languages.

Actually you could even put English inside the second table in order to make it more compliant with the Database Normalization:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization